# Full Page JS Animate Anchor : False Glitch

Tags: fullpage.js

Upon page refresh using animateAnchor: false, for a second I see the first image / slide presented on the site, rather than instantly loading the slide that is anchored. It looks like a small glitch. Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That makes total sense if you are importing the fullpage.js file before the closing body.

That way you'll have to wait for fullPage.js file to load and then to initialise and meanwhile you'll see your site as it is before using fullpage.js.

Try importing fullPage.js on the `head` of your site, this way initialisation will be faster.

Also, you can use the following CSS in your stylesheet so sections will be 100%  height even before loading fullPage.js:

```
#fullpage,
.section,
body,
.fp-tableCell,
html {
    height: 100%
}
```

Assuming `#fullpage` is your fullpage wrapper and that you use the default selectors for sections and slides. (`.slide`, `.section`)

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! I had already tried those two techniques. I’ve attached a js fiddle of what I’m working with, and a hosted version of the site, as you can’t refresh via an anchor in a js fiddle. To replicate; try refreshing the page having slid away from the first slide. There is also a white flash, I am assuming pre background color being applied. And when refreshing on the second section, you see the background color of the first section. 
http://tf-ref.com/play/43-js-fiddle/, https://jsfiddle.net/theoford01/evcmfok0/8/. Any further advice would be much appreciated.